# How to combine two javascript array into one and group by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello I'am new to programming and I stumble upon on grouping array data by date from two arrays.

here is my arrays:

```
header = [
    {"2019-04-22": "Sun, Apr 22, 2019"},
    {"2019-04-21": "Sat, Apr 21, 2019"},
]

body = [
    {"2019-04-22": "doing customer support”},
    {"2019-04-22": "reply to emails"},
    {"2019-04-21": "send message to customers"},
]
```

How do I group the arrays into one array as example below

```
combinearray = {
    "2019-04-22": [
        "Sun, Apr 22, 2019",
        "doing customer support",
        "reply to emails",
    ],
    "2019-04-21": [
        "Sat, Apr 21, 2019",
        "send message to customers",
    ],
}
```

Grouping two array data by date seems completely not easy for me I'm a beginner to javascript programming. I would appreciate any answers.

Comment: `combinearray` should be obj wrapped in `{}` instead of `[]`

Comment: Your desired output is not valid array

Comment: sorry for that.

Comment: The desired output seems like a slight smell to me. Is there any reason that each date is an array of *objects*, rather than just `"2019-04-21": [ "Sat, Apr 21, 2019", "send message to customers"]`? You repeat the key for every single object - what is the point of an object if the only portion you care about is the string?

Comment: @TylerRoper you are missing my point

Comment: I'm asking why you want an object structure that nests and repeats data where it doesn't seem to be at all necessary. I understand what you *want*, I just think you should consider it a bit. If you have a good reason for it, then sure, just pointing out that it seems redundant. You've made an array of key-value pairs where the key (seemingly) serves no purpose.

Comment: @TylerRoper, Yes you are right. I get it, thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- First use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to combine both arrays i.e `header` and `body`
- Then use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on that. And pass empty object as second argument(the initial value of accumulator).
- In inside `reduce()` callback use `Object.keys()[0]` to get date.
- Check if the date if date is not already key of accumulator set it to empty `[]`.
- Use `push()` to add the elements to the array.

**Note**: This will not remove reference to the real object in `header` and `body`.

```js
const header = [ {"2019-04-22": "Sun, Apr 22, 2019"}, {"2019-04-21": "Sat, Apr 21, 2019"} ]
const body = [ {"2019-04-22": "doing customer support"}, {"2019-04-22": "reply to emails"}, {"2019-04-21": "send message to customers"}, ]

const res = header.concat(body).reduce((ac,a) => {
  let key = Object.keys(a)[0];
  ac[key] = ac[key] || [];
  ac[key].push(a)
  return ac;
},{})
console.log(res)
```

However as mentioned in the comments there is no need to have object with keys. Just simple array of the values of that key are enough. For that `push()` `a[key]` instead of `a`.

```js
const header = [ {"2019-04-22": "Sun, Apr 22, 2019"}, {"2019-04-21": "Sat, Apr 21, 2019"} ]
const body = [ {"2019-04-22": "doing customer support"}, {"2019-04-22": "reply to emails"}, {"2019-04-21": "send message to customers"}, ]

const res = header.concat(body).reduce((ac,a) => {
  let key = Object.keys(a)[0];
  ac[key] = ac[key] || [];
  ac[key].push(a[key])
  return ac;
},{})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use combine arrays then use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

- used spread syntax to merge arrays
- use reduce to build an object in desired format
- Object.entries to get date and it's respective value
- Check if the date is already present as key on object or not, if it's already present push the value to it else create a new key

```js
let header = [{"2019-04-22": "Sun, Apr 22, 2019"},{"2019-04-21": "Sat, Apr 21, 2019"},]

let body = [{"2019-04-22": "doing customer support"},{"2019-04-22": "reply to emails"},{"2019-04-21": "send message to customers"},]


let final = [...header,...body].reduce((op,inp) => {
  let [key,value] = Object.entries(inp)[0]
  op[key] = op[key] || []
  op[key].push(value)
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @PHPcon always happy to help :)